# Are axiom schema of specification and axiom of specification the same terminology?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, terminology, axioms

I sometimes see books just having "axiom of specification" rather than lengthy "axiom schema of specification". Are these two the same thing?

Comment: Yes, they're the same thing. Officially it's not an axiom. Officially an axiom is a formula in a certain formal language - specification is a whole family of such formulas.

Comment: They are the same.
The prove is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/how-can-i-write-the-axiom-of-specification-as-a-sentence

Comment: For ZF it should be axiom schema or axiom scheme. Calling it an axiom is a hangover from the time when there was not a strict separation between first-order and second-order.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hehe, "separation" . . . I'll go now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; "axiom of specification" (or separation) is shorthand. It's technically incorrect, but clear.

---

. . . Unless you're working with **second-order set theory**! Then you can collect the whole scheme into one axiom. This is extremely rare, though, and almost without exception this isn't what people mean. But - especially if you're reading about old set theories - you may run into this.

Note that historically, the original presentation of Zermelo set theory was second order (well, actually, if I understand correctly it was informal, not even second-order; but I believe our historical understanding is that Zermelo *meant* the second-order version).